# CPU overloads with fans running high speed when laptop is plugged in to the power

Tags: drivers, power-management, fan, cpu-load, fancontrol

I have a MONSTER TULPAR T7 V20.5 laptop(a foreign brand). I have Ubuntu 23.04 installed with the kernel version of 6.2.0-20-generic x86_64.

The problem is CPU overload when the laptop is plugged into the power. The fans run so fast even if I don't do anything crazy. I have the Nvidia drivers installed. When I unplug the laptop and use it on battery, the CPU overloading problem goes away, fans working silently and all these things happen under the same power settings. Both plugged and unplugged(on-battery), the power settings are balanced and on-demand for Nvidia. I searched a lot about the problem. However, most solutions were for specific laptop brand.

I tried installing lm-sensors, however it was unable to detect my fans.

The system info if you cannot display the images:

- Hardware Model: MONSTER TULPAR T7 V20.5
- Firmware version: N.1.02MON04
- Memory: 16.0 GB
- Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H × 20
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060 Laptop GPU / Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
- OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04
- OS Type: 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 44.0
- Windowing System: X11
- Kernel Version: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
- Nvidia driver: 525.105.17

[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k49CX.png)

[nvidia driver info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UVg3.png)

Comment: what is using the CPU when you use `top`?

Comment: @rtaft When Chrome is open, it is usually at the top causing overload. However, it's not about that. Even when I just open IntelliJ and run a simple Java program, the fans go crazy. The problem only happens when laptop is plugged into the power.

Comment: Your battery overheats when charging  Physically check your fan (rotating?, dusty?, unblocked?). Physically check for dust coating the chips/heat sinks inside your computer. Remove dust __carefully__ (no water, no power, don't knock connectors loose, check manufacturer's web site). Dust is a very good insulator, and keeps the heat inside the chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. My laptop brand supports the Linux control center that was made by a company called Tuxedo. I installed that and finally, I am able to change the settings to Cool and breezy for fans.

[Tuxedo Control Center](https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Infos/Help-and-Support/Instructions/Add-TUXEDO-Computers-software-package-sources.tuxedo#)

I followed the alternative way that was listed there.

and after that, run:

```
sudo apt install tuxedo-control-center
```